# Pass data between embedded SWF and Flex

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, swfloader

I have a Flex project with an SWF object embedded with SWFLoader:

```
<mx:SWFLoader id="mySWFLoader" source="@Embed('Plant_Walking.swf')" creationComplete="onComplete()" />
```

The onComplete() function is embedded in the mxml file:

```
<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[

        public function onComplete() : void {
            mySWFLoader.content.addEventListener( "featureSelected" , handleEvent );
        }

        public function handleEvent( evt:Event ):void
        {

            var selectedInfo : String = mySWFLoader.content['itemname'];

            textinput.text = selectedInfo;
            label.text = selectedInfo;
        }


    ]]>
</fx:Script>
```

Inside this SWF object, written in AS3, when I click an object happens this:

```
itemname=ev.object.name;
dispatchEvent(new Event("featureSelected", true));
```

It call the event **featureSelected** and then it will call the **handleEvent** function. The problem is that I don't receive the value of the **itemname** parameter and, even though the parameter is declared in the SWF object:

```
public var itemname:String = "test";
```

I receive this error at runtime:

> [Fault] exception, information=ReferenceError: Error #1069: Property itemname not found on Main__embed_mxml_Plant_Walking_swf_1661400095 and there is no default value.

Why? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write following in your code. It will give the value.

```
var selectedInfo : String = evt.itemname;
```

Instead of:

```
var selectedInfo : String = mySWFLoader.content['itemname'];
```

**Edit:**

If above not work then, create custom event like:

```
public class FeatureSelectedEvent extends Event
{
    public static var FEATURE_SELECTED:String = "featureSelected";

    private var _itemname:String;
    public function get itemname():String { return _itemname }

    public function FeatureSelectedEvent (type:String, itemname:String, bubbles:Boolean=false, cancelable:Boolean=false)
    {
        super(type,bubbles,cancelable);
        _itemname = itemname;
    }

    override public function clone():Event
    {
        return new FeatureSelectedEvent(type, itemname, bubbles, cancelable);
    }
}
```

Then dispatch event like:

```
dispatchEvent(new FeatureSelectedEvent(FeatureSelectedEvent.FEATURE_SELECTED, ev.object.name));
```

You get parameter value like:

```
public function handleEvent( evt:Event ):void
 {
    var selectedInfo : String = event.itemname;
 }
```

Sorry, for any spelling mistake.

Comment: It doesn't work, I riceive this error message: "Error: Access of possibly undefined property itemname through a reference with static type flash.events:Event"

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the solution to my answer. I change the code of the handleEvent function in this way:

```
public function handleEvent( evt:Event ):void
        {   
            var selectedInfo:String = ((mySWFLoader.content as MovieClip).getChildAt(0) as Loader).content["itemname"]
            textinput.text = selectedInfo;
            label.text = selectedInfo;
        }
```